# Python and IDLE crashing unexpectedly on Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-idle, crash-log

I'm new to coding, trying to learn Python. I've been trying to use IDLE but it continues to crash unexpectedly. This is what I was able to dig up from the crash report:
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS) 
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000 
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread. 
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can report this to the Tkinter mailing list. They know better what to do.

Tkinter-discuss at python.org
https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tkinter-discuss

Also you can look at how to create bug reports for Python.

Have a look at [GuiProgramming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) section "GUI Design Tools and IDEs" in the mean time.